# Proving The Continuiuty

Tags: real-analysis

A function is monotonic on the interval $[a, b]$ and traverses all intermediate values between $f(b)$ and $f(a)$. Prove that the given function is continuous on the interval $[a, b]$.

From symmetry we can assume that the function is increasing on $[a, b]$ Now for a given $\epsilon>0$, for all $c\in[a, b]$ we have $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)\implies f(x)-f(b)<f(x)-f(c)<f(x)-f(a)\implies|f(x)-f(c)|<\min(f(b)-f(x), f(x)-f(a))$ So if $\epsilon>\min(f(b)-f(x), f(x)-f(a))$ then we are done and if $\epsilon \leq min(f(b)-f(x), f(x)-f(a))$ Now from here I don't know how to move forward?

Comment: Drawing a little picture might help to understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f$ increasing, you can prove more: for every $c\in(a,b)$, there exist
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\sup\{f(x):a\le x<c\},\qquad
\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x):c<x\le b\}
$$

Now think to what happens if for a particular $c$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)<\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)
$$

Complete the analysis for $a$ and $b$.